# Trying to Parse this JSON in IOS - seems v difficult is it Valid?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here is the JSON:

https://skrapapis.skrap.xyz/newApi/public/scrapapi/getServices

this is my code:

```
    if let url = URL(string: SERVICE_URL) {
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
          if let data = data {
             if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                
                    if let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                            
                            print(json!["result"]!)
                            
                        } catch {
                            print("Something went wrong")
                        }
                    }
                
                }
           }
       }.resume()
    }
```

Seems to be valid, but then parsing the 'result' part is not valid?

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: how are you parsing it? please add some code

Comment: So I parsed the first bit like this - json["result"] and then what i got is not really parsable...

Comment: not letting me add code

Comment: basically I want easy array of 7 items from the "result"

Comment: this is the API URL: https://skrapapis.skrap.xyz/newApi/public/scrapapi/getServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode the `JSON` using `Decodable` protocol conformance instead of `JSONSeraialization` which is outdated. Here is the code:

```
let json = """
{
    "code": 0,
    "description": "Services found successfuly",
    "result": [
        {
            "service_id": 2,
            "service_name": "Skip Hire",
            "description": "<p>Ideal for disposing of large amounts of building, construction and garden waste. Skips come&nbsp;in varied sizes and are measured in yards.</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/skip_hire.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 1,
            "service_name": "Grab Hire",
            "description": "<p>Ideal for disposing of&nbsp;large amounts of building, construction and garden waste.&nbsp;&nbsp;A&nbsp;grab lorry uses a grab arm and bucket to collect and clear away large quantities of waste from otherwise inaccessible areas</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/grab_hire.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 3,
            "service_name": "Cage Hire",
            "description": "<p>An alternative removal solution to skip hire, suitable for all types of waste removals and includes a professional and experienced driver who will assist you in loading your waste. Ideal for removal of bulky items or for locations where a skip isn&#39;t practical, such as more congested roads or busy urban areas with parking restrictions.</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/cage_hire.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 29,
            "service_name": "Aggregates",
            "description": "<p>Aggregates give&nbsp;volume, stability, resistance to wear or erosion, and other desired physical properties to the finished product.</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/aggregate.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 80,
            "service_name": "Concrete",
            "description": "<p>Ready Mix Concrete is a batch of concrete that is pre-mixed before being delivered to the project site. Tell us the volume required, and we have it delivered to site in a volume metric vehicle.&nbsp;</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/concrete.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 43,
            "service_name": "Portaloo",
            "description": "<p>We have portaloos available for varied workforce sizes, hired on a weekly basis with an additional haulage charge.</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/portallo.png"
        },
        {
            "service_id": 60,
            "service_name": "Plant Hire",
            "description": "<p>Plant hire consists of a varirty of tools, plant and equipment necessary for construction site operations.&nbsp;</p>",
            "img_url": "/service_images/plant_hire.png"
        }
    ]
}
"""
let data = Data(json.utf8)

struct Response: Decodable {
    let code: Int
    let description: String
    let result: [Result]
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let serviceId: Int
    let serviceName, description, imgUrl: String
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response.result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: ok its working I can access the first item using response.result[0] and now how do I get the "serviceName" value?

Comment: Did you try `. serviceName`?